# How does Asio include a low-level socket interface based on the BSD socket API?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

From Asio documentation:

```
The Asio library includes a low-level socket interface based on the BSD socket
API, which is widely implemented and supported by extensive literature. It is
also used as the basis for networking APIs in other languages, like Java. This
low-level interface is designed to support the development of efficient and
scalable applications.
```

So is it the case that Asio library re-implements the low-level socket interface? Or is Asio library socket interface a wrapper for BSD socket API/Winsock with a lot of features? If the re-implementation is the case, I expect to see a lot of kernel code.

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: Yes, of course it is not an easy read.

Comment: I believe it would be a wrapper around various platform specific sockets implementations. Using boost does not suddenly add a kernel mode driver component to an application. Imagine the deployment and servicing nightmare that would be, assuming you got past the administrative rights needed to install such.

Comment: Tanveer Bader Yes, I suspect so. When I search the source code for <sys/socket.h>, I can only find one header file containing this header. And I have difficulties in locating how the actual call to Linux socket(int domain, int type, int protocol) is made, or it may be hidden from layers and layers of macro.

Comment: It's "hidden" in "layers and layers" of code. In particular generic templates, and service/handle separation. No macros, of course, since this is C++ and not C.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the socket implementation abstracts the underlying OS implementation. Both WinInet and linux sockets are similar to BSD sockets.

The "lowlevel" API would be in that `asio::ip::basic_socket<...>::read_some` and `...::write_some` are on the same level as the BSD level API.

Indeed, the service *implementations* relay to the underlying call, abstracting away the (implementation specific) details of blocking vs. unblocking IO and waiting for ready sockets (without requiring you to use threads).

You **can** still use the native API's with the raw socket handles, by using the `native_handle()` member function from inside the service objects (e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/native_handle.html).

> Be careful not to break implementation invariants, though. E.g. calling `::close` on such a handle, or changing the blocking mode will invite spurious bugs and deadlocks.